# Calculate percentage between two datafarmes

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

First dataframe `df1` is,

```
df1 = data.frame('gen' = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 'mm' = c(10, 20, 30, 40), 'nn' = c(50,60,70,80))
  gen mm nn
1   a 10 50
2   b 20 60
3   c 30 70
4   d 40 80
```

Second dataframe `df2` is,

```
df2 = data.frame('gen' = c('x', 'y'), 'mm' = c(10,20), 'nn' = c(20,30))
  gen mm nn
1   x  10 20
2   y  20 30
```

I want to calculate percentage of `df1` over all the `df2` values.

Excepted output,

```
  gen    x.1   y.1   x.2   y.2
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         0   -50   150  66.67
2 b       100     0   200 100.00  
3 c       200    50   250 133.33 
4 d       300   100   300 167.67
```

For example,

The general formula

**(df1-df2)/df2*100**

Consider `a`

**(10-10)/10*100 = 0** (`x.1`)

**(10-20)/20*100 = -50** (`y.1`)

**(50-20)/20*100 = 150** (`x.2`)

**(50-30)/30*100 = 66.67** (`y.2`)

and so on...

Thank you...

Comment: Both tables have 10, 20, 50, so it's not immediately clear to me when your formulas are referring to which elements of which table. Can you explain more pls?

Comment: Added a general formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-gen) %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% pivot_longer(-gen), by = "name") %>% 
  mutate(value.y = (value.x - value.y) / value.y * 100, .keep = "unused") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("gen.y", "name"), values_from = "value.y") %>% 
  rename(gen = gen.x, x.1 = x_mm, y.1 = y_mm, x.2 = x_nn, y.2 = y_nn)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  gen     x.1   y.1   x.2   y.2
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         0   -50   150  66.7
2 b       100     0   200 100  
3 c       200    50   250 133. 
4 d       300   100   300 167.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
# Convert df1 and df2 to data.table format
setDT(df)
setDT(df2, keep.rownames = c("id"))
# Melt df1 and df2 to long format
df.melt <- melt(df, id.vars = "gen", variable.factor = FALSE)
df2.melt <- melt(df2, id.vars = c("id", "gen"), variable.factor = FALSE)
# Perform left join
ans <- df2.melt[df.melt, on = .(variable), allow.cartesian = TRUE]
# Create new colnames
ans[, id2 := rowid(i.gen, gen)]
ans[, name := paste(gen, id2, sep = ".")]
# Perform calulation
ans[, new.value := 100 * (i.value - value) / value]
# Cast to wide format
dcast(ans, i.gen ~ name, value.var = "new.value")
#    i.gen x.1 x.2 y.1       y.2
# 1:     a   0 150 -50  66.66667
# 2:     b 100 200   0 100.00000
# 3:     c 200 250  50 133.33333
# 4:     d 300 300 100 166.66667
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am getting an error at `ans <- df2.melt[df.melt, on = .(variable), allow.cartesian = TRUE]` which is `Error in colnamesInt(i, unname(on), check_dups = FALSE) : 
  argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[1]='variable'`

Comment: strange.. no error here... have you ran all of the code in the answer above on your sample data?

Comment: Yeah ran all the code

Comment: the code is okay